# Firebug stops window.location after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a strange issue with firebug. When I do an ajax call with jquery and in the success method do window.location.href = "to some url" the browser doesn't go to that page.

If I disable firebug it works. I don't get any errors in the console and I tried to restart the browser I also have reset the firebug options with no success. Does anybody had the same issues?

I got this issue on other pages that also use window.locaton.href that worked before.

Comment: make sure there is no any `console` `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [has been reported as a Firebug issue before](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6082), but with no STR, and the reporter later failed to reproduce it. I would assume it's fixed in recent Firefox+Firebug versions (try nightlies), but if not, please post a note to that issue.

Comment: Thanks must have been that or a setting somewhere. I reinstalled firefox without deleteing my settings and I still got the same issue. I tried completely reinstall firefox (removing my settings) then it worked. So my guess it's a setting issue somewhere or I got newer version of firebug or firefox

Answer (score 0):

Please check that mistakenly had you putted any breakpoints on the line of `window.location.href` line. If so firebug will stop control on that line.
And when you stop debugging through firebug. It will works fine.

Firebug or any debugger does not prevents any code